# Is it possible to speed up crosstool-ng builds once errors have occured?

Tags: build, cross-compiling

I am using crosstool-ng to build a tolchain for beagleboard-xm. The build proceeds in a manner depicted below:

> [INFO ] 
>   ================================================================= [INFO ]  Retrieving needed toolchain components' tarballs [INFO ] 
>   Retrieving needed toolchain components' tarballs: done in 0.51s (at
>   00:08) [INFO ] 
>   ================================================================= [INFO ]  Extracting and patching toolchain components [INFO ] 
>   Extracting and patching toolchain components: done in 7.91s (at 00:16)
>   [INFO ] 
>   ================================================================= [INFO ]  Installing GMP [INFO ]  Installing GMP: done in 140.48s (at
>   02:36) [INFO ] 
>   ================================================================= [INFO ]  Installing MPFR [INFO ]  Installing MPFR: done in 36.01s (at
>   03:13) [INFO ] 
>   ================================================================= [INFO ]  Installing PPL . .
>
> `

Now, after 50 mins of compiling, it breaks with an error:

> [ERROR]    configure: error: expat is missing or unusable"

I installed the required package (in Ubuntu 10.04) but the error is a non-issue. Earlier I was able to get to steps where it had successfully installed the  compiler and there were no errors till then. I was wondering if there is a way to have the tool skip over previously successfull steps, saving time? Is it even possible with the way crosstool-ng works?

Comment: *Please excuse formatting. Thanks.

Comment: Found it. "ct-ng --help" does not give the right information. Use "ct-ng help". Look up the option to RESTART build.

Comment: For future googlers, fix this error with `sudo apt-get install libexpat1-dev`. (Simply installing expat doesn't fix it.)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Run ct-ng like this

> CT_DEBUG_CT_SAVE_STEPS=1 ct-ng build

After crashing at a certain step, just find the step in the list produced by

> ct-ng list-steps

At which point you can resume the build by running

> RESTART=libc_start_files ct-ng build

Answer (score 13):

yes, current crosstool-ng has support this feature.

1. enable this feature in menuconfig

for `ct-ng menuconfig`, config `Paths and misc options` like this

```
───────────────────── Paths and misc options ─────────────────────
[*] Debug crosstool-NG
[ ]   Pause between every steps
[*]   Save intermediate steps
[*]     gzip saved states
[*]   Interactive shell on failed commands
```

2.when do build, for each step done successfully, you will see something like this:

`Saving state to restart at step 'xxx'...`

3.when fail, after fix it, then use `ct-ng LAST_SUCCESSFUL_STETP_NAME+` to continue build

my example:

```
CLi@PC-CLI-1 ~/develop/crosstool-ng/crosstool-ng-1.18.0_build
$ ct-ng list-steps
Available build steps, in order:
  - libc_check_config
  - companion_libs_for_build
  - binutils_for_build
  - companion_libs_for_host
  - binutils_for_host
  - cc_core_pass_1
  - kernel_headers
  - libc_start_files
  - cc_core_pass_2
  - libc
  - cc_for_build
  - cc_for_host
  - libelf_for_target
  - binutils_for_target
  - debug
  - test_suite
  - finish
Use "<step>"p>" as action to execute only that step"+<step>"lt;step>" as action to execute up to tha"<step>+"se "<step>+" as action to execute from that step onward.

CLi@PC-CLI-1 ~/develop/crosstool-ng/crosstool-ng-1.18.0_build
$ ct-ng libc+
[INFO ]  Performing some trivial sanity checks
[INFO ]  Build started 20130801.120248
[INFO ]  Building environ'libc'ariables
[EXTRA]  Preparing working directories
[EXTRA]  Restoring state at step 'libc', as requested.
[INFO ]  =================================================================
[INFO ]  Installing C library
[EXTRA]    Configuring C library
[EXTRA]    Building C library
[01:55] /
```

for more explaination, refer my post:[crosstool-ng build for xscale](http://www.crifan.com/crosstool_ng_1_18_0_compile_for_xscale/)

Answer (score 2):

Another big time saver - configure crosstool-ng for parallel job threads when building on a host with multi-core CPU..

```sh
# launch menuconfig

./ct-ng menuconfig

# Path and misc options -> Set Number of parallel jobs - note default is 0!
```

This should signifficantly speed up your build jobs.

Obviously, set this value accordingly per your host systems CPU arch - ensure to leave at least one or two cores available for host OS and other threads...

Cheers!

Comment: You don't have to change the config for that, just run `ct-ng build.4` to have 4 parallel jobs. 
https://crosstool-ng.github.io/docs/build/

Comment: There is logic built into ct scripts which sets the number of jobs to the number of CPUs if  CT_PARALLEL_JOBS=0. So usually it is better not to set it manually. See scripts/crosstool-NG.sh:

    AUTO_JOBS=$[ BUILD_NCPUS + 1 ]
    [ ${CT_PARALLEL_JOBS} -eq 0 ] && CT_JOBSFLAGS="${CT_JOBSFLAGS} -j${AUTO_JOBS}"
    [ ${CT_PARALLEL_JOBS} -gt 0 ] && CT_JOBSFLAGS="${CT_JOBSFLAGS} -j${CT_PARALLEL_JOBS}"
    CT_JOBSFLAGS="${CT_JOBSFLAGS} -l${CT_LOAD}"